# Mongo not found in php.ini - ext not loading

Tags: php, windows, mongodb

I am desperately trying to download and use mongo and I am having one problem after another.  I have finally been able to successfully download mongo and use it from the command line shell.  But after I downloaded the php drivers I can't seem to get a connection via php.

I checked my php.ini file and it looks as if it is not loading the mongo extension.

I am running a 64 bit machine, and wamp 2.2 which includes php 5.3.8 and apache 2.2.21.  When I run php.ini it get this:

```
System  Windows NT xxxx-PC 6.1 build 7601 (Windows 7 Home Premium Edition 
Service Pack 1) AMD64
Build Date  Sep 16 2011 21:25:01
Compiler    MSVC9 (Visual C++ 2008)
Architecture    x64
Configure Command   cscript /nologo configure.js "--enable-snapshot-build" "--with-
pdo-oci=C:\php-sdk\php53dev\vc9\x64\deps\instantclient_10_2\sdk,shared" "--with-
oci8=C:\php-sdk\php53dev\vc9\x64\deps\instantclient_10_2\sdk,shared" "--with-
oci8-11g=C:\php-sdk\php53dev\vc9\x64\deps\instantclient_11_2\sdk,shared" "--disable-
debug-pack" "--disable-static-analyze"
Server API  Apache 2.0 Handler
Virtual Directory Support   enabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   C:\Windows
Loaded Configuration File   C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.21\bin\php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files     (none)
Additional .ini files parsed    (none)
PHP API     20090626
PHP Extension   20090626
Zend Extension  220090626
Zend Extension Build    API220090626,TS,VC9
PHP Extension Build     API20090626,TS,VC9
Debug Build     no
Thread Safety   enabled
Zend Memory Manager     enabled
Zend Multibyte Support  disabled
IPv6 Support    enabled
Registered PHP Streams  php, file, glob, data, http, ftp, zip, compress.zlib, phar
Registered Stream Socket Transports     tcp, udp
Registered Stream Filters   convert.iconv.*, mcrypt.*, mdecrypt.*, string.rot13, 
string.toupper, string.tolower, string.strip_tags, convert.*, consumed, dechunk, zlib.*
```

I have googled my problem and have read a few different suggestions.  I have tried a few of them and it doesn't seem to fix it.  I have been googling and reading posts on this for the last few hours with no success so please leave a detailed or step by step solution (for a newbie) and not just a link to another post.  Thank you much.

Comment: looks like you found a solution to your question here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891551/mongodb-mongo-not-found-not-win32-application

Answer (score 0):

You put `php_mongo.dll` in your php\ext folder, and added `extension=php_mongo.dll` to your php.ini?

Comment: Let me start by saying thank you for the response. This is basic install which i have tried 100 times now and it is not working.  From some blogs i have read i need to configure my stack to properly communicated.  Something with a tradition wamp stack on 64 bit doesn't work right with mongo.  I have found many posts stating this but no one is giving a step by step (newbie) solution on how to fix it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Also remember to start the mongo service, before you try to connect.

A note, **mongod.exe** is the server, and **mongo.exe** is the administrative shell, you have to run mongod.exe first.

P.D.

Sure you have seen this but try to follow the docs in mongodb website, it is very easy (even it tells you how to install mongo as a service)

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Quickstart+Windows

Comment: Let me start by saying thank you for the response. This is basic install which i have tried 100 times now and it is not working. From some blogs i have read i need to configure my stack to properly communicated. Something with a tradition wamp stack on 64 bit doesn't work right with mongo. I have found many posts stating this but no one is giving a step by step (newbie) solution on how to fix it. Thanks.